# What does "Self-indulging" mean?

Tags: meaning

In the Dictionary, Self-indulging = characterized by doing or tending to do exactly what one wants, especially when this involves pleasure or idleness.

I can't understand the term by just reading its definition. I want to understand the term through the context, probably in a sentence or phrase.

Can anyone give an example that can help me to understand that term clearly?

Comment: You can try seeing the word used in context through Google Books (be sure to try variations like *self-indulgent*). Also, I'm quite surprised that whatever dictionary you found that definition in, didn't also include at least one example sentence.

Comment: Lot more example sentences at [Collins dictionary definition](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/self-indulgent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone who is self-indulgent gives themselves a lot of treats.As a synonym,it also means

> spoiling yourself

to spoil means "to treat someone very well, esp. by being too generous"

or

> pampering yourself

to pamper means "to treat with too much kindness and attention"

As a broader definition  "An indulgent person would be a person that is self-consumed; maybe talks about themselves and their stuff and they don't really listen or are interested in others' lives, events or things; everything is about the self-indulgent person."

Answer (score 0):

Self indulgent means plainly, indulge one's self in something. This can be anything from buying yourself that one thing that you want or  Sleeping  for ten minutes because you don't want to get up synonyms:  hedonistic, pleasure-seeking, sybaritic, indulgent, luxurious,

Use in sentence:

Ohh, that looks very nice. I'm going to get it for myself.   <= This is an act of self indulgence.

Answer (score 0):

Our family, we believe has a member that is self-indulgent here are some of our examples:

1. Earns $500.00 per wk but buys Gucci $500.00 flipflops.
2. Buys a purebred expensive dog, then sleeps in every day and doesn't get up to let the dog out or feed it until noon or later.
3. Buy's all they want to excess and debt.
4. When only allotted $200.00 food budget buys prime rib instead of food that will feed a multitude and variety Of people because that's what they like.
5. Expresses discontent, complains about not having, or wanting more.
6. Makes excuses when asked to contribute, give any effort, share, or help.

Answer (score -1):

Self indulgent is all about one self.. To be into one self.. It's all about me and how I lije it.